# Using LINQ .Join() method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework

I'd like to use the `.Join()` method in LINQ to perform the following SQL:

`select * from Enquiries e, QuoteLines q where e.EnquiryId = q.EnquiryId and e.AccountNum = '123' and q.LineNumber = 'ABC123'`

The parameters used for `AccountNum` and `LineNumber` will be dynamically passed to the method.

How would I transfer this to use the LINQ `.Join()` method?

```
public ActionResult EnquirySearch(string id)
{
    var enquiries = new List<Enquiries>();    

    if(id.Contains(' '))
    {
        string[] searchArr = id.Split(' ');
        // want to do my LINQ here
        // this will be split so the first element in the array is the AccountNum
        // and the second element in the array is the LineNumber
    }
    else
    {
        enquiries = context.Enquiries.Where(x=>x.QuoteRef.Contains(id) 
        || x.AccountNum.Contains(id) || x.Owner.Contains(id));
    }
    return View(enquiries);
}
```

Comment: Is there a foreign key relationship?  If so, you won't even need a join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier to express a join in an expression query, where it would be something like:

```
var query = from e in Enquiries
            join q in QuoteLines on e.EnquiryId equals q.EnquiryId
            where e.AccountNum == accountNum && q.LineNumber == lineNumber
            select new { Enquiry = e, QuoteLine = q };
```

Or you could filter "early" - which would make a difference in LINQ to Objects, but almost certainly not in LINQ to SQL / EF:

```
var query = from e in Enquiries
            where e.AccountNum == accountNum
            join q in QuoteLines.Where(qq => qq.LineNumber == lineNumber)
              on e.EnquiryId equals q.EnquiryId
            select new { Enquiry = e, QuoteLine = q };
```

Comment: I only want to select the data in my Enquiry Table, is that possible?

Comment: @BiffBaffBoff: Absolutely - just change the final line to `select e`

Comment: Thanks alot! So, out of curiosity, is there no way to do it using the `.Join()` LINQ method?

Comment: @BiffBaffBoff: Yes - all query expressions are translated into non-query expressions. But it gets ugly pretty quickly - I use method calls directly for simple jobs, but use query expressions for joins and complex queries.

Comment: Alright, sounds like a good principle to use, I shall follow suit :)

Answer (score 1):

Using Join()

```
var query = context.Enquiries.Where(e=>e.AccountNum == accountNum)
.Join(context.QuoteLines.Where(q=>q.LineNumber==lineNumber),
 e => e.EnquiryID, q => q.EnquiryID,(e,q)=>e);
```

This seems trickier but it does have intellisense support.
I've no idea how the fourth argument works but it does.

Comment: Think of the fourth argument as the "SELECT clause" for the JOIN. For each pairing of `Enquiry e` with `QuoteLines q` that ends up in the join result, the fourth argument lets you select which parts of the pairing you end up with in the end result. It's a lambda function that receives the paired `e` and `q` and lets you return a new anonymous instance based on them. In your example, `(e,q)=>e;` ends up returning just the `Enquiry` part.